# How do I align my text in a label to the right side?

Tags: c#, winforms, alignment, label

So here is my file label. If the label is too long, it will go off the screen thus making me have to scroll.

I've tried the following properties (separate times):

- `RightToLeft` as Yes
- `ContentAlignment` as BottomRight or TopRight

However, none of them are working. What is the correct property?

[image: File Label]

Comment: If I set it `AutoSize` to false then it will cut the label text short.

Comment: You have to make the box bigger then. :-) If you use `AutoSize = false` you can specifiy the box-size.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try setting `AutoSize` to `false` (that makes a fixed size box). Then you can use the `TextAlign` property to align the text - e.g. use `MiddleRight`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Alright thanks to anybody who helped :) Since you were first I'll give this to you.

Answer (score 19):

```
Label label = new Label();
label.AutoSize = false;    
label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Comment: Yes, but from properties window not programmatically so I answered it, thanks.

Comment: yes this much better and clear to what answers already present, Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

In the properties window:

- Set `AutoSize = False`
- Set `TextAlign = MiddleRight`

In the designer:

- Resize the label so it's wide enough to fit whatever potential text you try to set it to.

Answer (score 4):

Just **Remove** the `autosize = true` and set `RightToLeft = true`
and the label will now grow to the left.

Answer (score 2):

Sample (WPF):

```
Label label = new Label();
label.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes AutoSize = false and RightToLeft = true will work. Note that when you set RightToLeft, the strange c# 2010 TextAlign TopLeft becomes aligned correctly to the right. If I set that to Top/Middle Right, the text jumps to the left instead!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

your_label_name.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;

Answer (score -1):

Set `Autosize=true` and `Textalign=MiddleRight`.

Comment: All other answers say to set `AutoSize` to false - can you explain why your answer is correct and the others are not?

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do to label to make it work:

1. `Textalign = MiddleRight`
2. `Anchor = top and right`