# C# Form text-align not working

Tags: c#

i have created this label in design.
label TextAlign = MiddleCenter;
label AutoSize = false;

it looks fine in design but when i run it always align Left. No idea what is going on!

```
        // load user image
        picCerImage.Image = Image.FromFile(Global.avatarPath);
        // load user fullname;
        lbeCerFullName.Text = Global.userFullName;
```

this code is from FormLoad event and here is a picture when i run:
[image]

Sorry about my English!

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of label?

Comment: yes, always longer than the text that i load! you can see the label background image in there!

Comment: no luck. May be a bug or something? :(

Comment: Try Trim the userFullName before setting them to label text. If you stored them on DB with nchar type, you'll have trailing space

Comment: actually the value of FullName is stored in DB, i will try. Hope it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work on that:

1. set the ***TextAlign*** to ***TopRight***
2. set the ***Anchor*** to ***top and left.***

Answer (score 0):

OK! I found the problem with help of Martheen. Trim the string before loading it! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can always look for other answers to problems like yours, like, for example, in [How do I align my text in a label to the right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218729/how-do-i-align-my-text-in-a-label-to-the-right-side).

Anyway, maybe this will work:

1. Adjust the label size so it's larger than the text.
2. Set the label **Autosize** property to *False*
3. Set the label **TextAlign** to *TopRight*, *MiddleRight* or *BottomRight*, depending on your choice.

I hope this works for you. Good luck!

Comment: i know how to align text but the problem here is it not working!

Comment: Maybe if you share more of your code and configurations with us, we can help you better. Docking? Anchors?

Comment: Excelent, @tuankhoa1996! If it was based on any of our answers, please mark it as that so other people know. If you figure it out by yourself, write it down in your original post :)